# Combination of lists from two lists of strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have two lists and I need to do a combination of strings from these lists, I have tried but I think it's not very efficient for larger lists.

```
data = ['keywords', 'testcases']
data_combination = ['data', 'index']
final_list = []
for val in data:
    for comb in range(len(data_combination)):
        if comb == 1:
            final_list.append([val]  + data_combination)
        else:
            final_list.append([val, data_combination[comb]])
```

My Output is:

```
 [['keywords', 'data'],
 ['keywords', 'data', 'index'],
 ['testcases', 'data'],
 ['testcases', 'data', 'index']]
```

Is there any more pythonic way to achieve it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A list comprehension is one way. "Pythonic" is subjective and I would not claim this is the most readable or desirable method.

```
data = ['keywords', 'testcases']
data_combination = ['data', 'index']

res = [[i] + data_combination[0:j] for i in data \
       for j in range(1, len(data_combination)+1)]

# [['keywords', 'data'],
#  ['keywords', 'data', 'index'],
#  ['testcases', 'data'],
#  ['testcases', 'data', 'index']]
```

Comment: Is this more efficient than the OP's solution? Just curious.

Comment: List comprehensions are the most efficient in most cases, so should be here.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly even more Pythonic:

**Code**

```
data = ["keywords", "testcases"]
data_combination = ["data", "index"]

[[x] + data_combination[:i] for x in data for i, _ in enumerate(data_combination, 1)]
```

Output

```
[['keywords', 'data'],
 ['keywords', 'data', 'index'],
 ['testcases', 'data'],
 ['testcases', 'data', 'index']]
```